# "For/during/on/in the first two nights"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

> He slept very well for the first two nights, but on the third night, he did not.

Can I say “in the first two nights”, “during the first two nights” or “on the first two nights” instead of “for the first two nights” in the sentence above? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the prepositions altogether:

> He slept very well the first two nights, but the third, he did 
>   not.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. He slept very well **for** the first two nights, but on the third night, he did not.
> 2. He slept very well **in** the first two nights, but on the third night, he did not.
> 3. He slept very well **during** the first two nights, but on the third night, he did not.
> 4. He slept very well **on** the first two nights, but on the third night, he did not.

All of these would work but (2) is the least appropriate. "In the night" usually refers to the specific time of day and not a specific night in a series of nights:

> They came in the night.
>
> The thief sneaks around in the night.